# How to use ReplaySubject in ReactiveKit

Tags: swift, reactivekit

I have this in RxSwift:

```
func foo() -> Observable<Int> {
    let subject = RxSwift.ReplaySubject<Int>.create(bufferSize: 1)
    return subject.asObservable()
}
```

How do I implement the same concept in ReactiveKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ReactiveKit 3 that is currently in beta (rk3 branch) you can do:

```
func foo() -> Signal<Int, NoError> {
  let subject = ReplaySubject<Int, NoError>(bufferSize: 1)
  return subject.toSignal()
}
```

In ReactiveKit 2 ReplaySubject is generalised over events:

```
func foo() -> Stream<Int> {
  let subject = ReplaySubject<StreamEvent<Int>>(bufferSize: 1)
  return Stream(rawStream: subject.toRawStream())
}
```

or

```
func foo() -> Operation<Int, Error> {
  let subject = ReplaySubject<OperationEvent<Int>>(bufferSize: 1)
  return Operation(rawStream: subject.toRawStream())
}
```

Comment: Close! Thanks for the assist, but it looks like your second block of code should have `return Stream(rawStream: subject.toRawStream())` instead of `return subject.toStream()`. If that sounds right to you and you edit the code, I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Now I just have to figure out how to bind a stream to this ReplaySubject...